# Can Google hangout API place a call and log outcome?

Tags: api, phone-call, voice, google-hangouts

looking here it seems it is possible, but I'm not a Java guy.
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.telephone

I have an ongoing issue with my incoming phone lines not working and I have no way of knowing until someone calls my cell and says your number has been busy for hours what's up...

I'd like to make a simple extension/app that will dial my number once an hour, log the outcome of the call, and notify me (email/sms doesn't matter) if it was busy or other error. If the lines are working it will ring always and go to VM if I'm on the phone. When it dies, the caller either gets a busy, fast busy, or just dropped after 30 sec.

The phone company has been of no use in fixing the issue, so I want to log the status to prove just how often it happens.